# How can I modify nodes

Tags: nodes

How can I insert two little boxes bellow a node in a tikZ picture and then fill those with numbers like this?[image]

Comment: page 51 tikz manual tutorial  - http://ctan.imsc.res.in/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `label` which you make `rectangle split` node from the `shapes.multipart` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=2em,
    label={[draw,rectangle split,%<-selects shape
        rectangle split parts=2,%<- 2 node parts
        rectangle split horizontal,%<- horizontal split
        yshift=-1ex]below:{10\nodepart{two}10}}]{1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to create several of those, it makes sense to combine these keys to some style.